# how to parse following JSON using object mapper

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

This is the JSON

[{
    "start_hour": "08:00:00",
    "end_hour": "10:00:00",
    "call_duration": "30"
}]

I tried to parse as follows

```
class DoctorAvailablityResponseData: Mappable {
var startDateHour : String?
var callDuration : Int?
var endDateHour : String?
required init?(_ map: Map){

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    callDuration <- map["call_duration"]
    endDateHour <- map["end_hour"]
    startDateHour <- map["start_hour"]

  }
}
```

and

```
let user = Mapper<ResponseDoctorAvailablity>().map(response.result.value)
```

But it breaks while parsing , found nil value .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data type is wrong.  You need to give "DoctorAvailablityResponseData", but you gave ResponseDoctorAvailablity for mapping.

```
    let user = Mapper<ResponseDoctorAvailablity>().map(response.result.value)
```

Example

```
    class Doctor: Mappable {
        var startDateHour : String?
        var callDuration : String?
        var endDateHour : String?
        required init?(_ map: Map){

        }

        func mapping(map: Map) {
            callDuration <- map["call_duration"]
            endDateHour <- map["end_hour"]
            startDateHour <- map["start_hour"]

        }
    }

    // Sample Response
    let response : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary.init(object: "08:00:00", forKey: "start_hour");
    response.setValue("10:00:00", forKey: "end_hour");
    response.setValue("30", forKey: "call_duration");

    // Convert response result to dictionary type. It is very easy.
    let userdic = Mapper<Doctor>().map(response) // Map to correct datatype.
    NSLog((userdic?.callDuration)!);

    // If you result is nested object. you will easily get zero index position object and parse it.
    let nestedObjectArray :NSArray = NSArray.init(array: [response]);

    let userArray = Mapper<Doctor>().map(nestedObjectArray[0])


    NSLog((userArray?.callDuration)!);
```

Comment: yeah this code working
But i don't want to make a dictionary for that , is anything wrong with json ?

Comment: i can do this also
                let user = Mapper<DoctorAvailablityResponseData>().map(response.result.value?.objectAtIndex(0))

Comment: Can you give response.result.value please?

Comment: I thought, your response result is nested object.

Comment: May be your solution is,
let user = Mapper<DoctorAvailablityResponseData>().map(response.result.value[0])

Answer (score 1):

As per user JSON 'call_duration' is also string type. Change line

```
var callDuration : Int?
```

to:

```
var callDuration : String?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also wrap them all in a 'guard' statement that way if you do get a nil you can pass in 0 to represent that an item was empty or had no length.

Comment: problem is not about nil , problem is about way to parse , i am able to parse with nsjsonserialization

Answer (score 0):

Your json data looks like an array in which first element is a dictionary.

`[{ "start_hour": "08:00:00", "end_hour": "10:00:00", "call_duration": "30" }]`.

In addition to changing the call_duration type to String? have you tried ensuring that you are actually passing a dictionary and not an array to the map function? Try passing just this and see if it works.

`{ "start_hour": "08:00:00", "end_hour": "10:00:00", "call_duration": "30" }`